# How to hide firebase dynamic link debugging info

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm integrating [**firebase dynamic link**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually) integration & it work pretty well. Except the fact that whatever I pass as query parameter in **link** attribute it display those information in web link.

I'm using following attribute info to generate deep link.

```
{
   "longDynamicLink": "https://xyz.app.goo.gl/?link=https://yah.co?event_type=1&apn=com.droid.test&ibi=com.iOS.test&isi=232323232"
}
```

In this example it generated but debug info(using ?d=1 at the end of deep-link) display **event_type** info.
Any suggestion if there is way to hide info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this safe to pass query parameter in Firebase Dynamic "link" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188083/is-this-safe-to-pass-query-parameter-in-firebase-dynamic-link-attribute)

Comment: Replied in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188083/is-this-safe-to-pass-query-parameter-in-firebase-dynamic-link-attribute/49211788#49211788