# Is this safe to pass query parameter in Firebase Dynamic "link" attribute

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm integrating [firebase dynamic linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually) for Android & iOS application. What I found is query parameter I passed in **link** attribute is not safe. I can copy link form debug detail (by appending ?d=1 at the end of deep link).

My understanding says we should not pass any important information here as query parameter, but is there way to safeguard this !!

Answer (score 0):

Its only as secret as a regular link - so if you wouldn't pass some important detail in a standard URL, then don't put it in a dynamic link. If you have some secret information, it is always best to link that to a proper auth system.

If you write the data into a system like Firestore or the Realtime Database you can use security rules to restrict its access, then pass a reference in the dynamic link parameters. The specifics of what to restrict in the rules will depend on your use case.